# How To Change WordPress REST API Taxonomy Orderby Parameter?

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, vue.js, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to order taxonomies, being pulled by the WordPress REST API, by name. What I currently have is:

```
http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?per_page=100&orderby=name
```

So in theory what this should be doing is getting a list of the categories on the website, up to 100, and order those categories by their name.

When I do this however it gives me up to 100 categories using the per_page parameter, but when it seems to be ignoring the orderby parameter and I'm not sure why. It says that 'name' is an excepted option for the orderby parameter, but it is still ordering by the default order which is ID.

Is there something I am doing wrong or a setting I need to turn on so I can use the orderby parameter with taxonomies?

Comment: According to [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/categories/#list-categories) `&orderby=name` is redundant (as it's the default `orderby` value). Make sure you don't confuse `name` with `slug` and that the `name` value is actually what you think it is, especially for the categories which seem to be misplaced (i.e: they might have a leading empty space). Also make sure no plugin/theme alters your query (best way to test is switching to a default theme and disabling all plugins).

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Aftering going through my theme and plugins I found the culprit. The plugin 'Category Order and Taxonomy Terms Order' is what is causing it to not orderby the parameter I set.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentarion](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/categories/#list-categories) your call is correct.

You can see it working here:

```
http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?order=asc&orderby=name
http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?order=desc&orderby=name
```

You should be looking an issue serverside (WordPress configuration, server configuration etc).

What version of WordPress are you using?